# Order by child record value(s) that can be empty

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've tried some combinations but I just don't understand how to do the following:

Lets say I have tables **Requests** and **RequestActivities**. I need to get all request sorted by **RequestActivity.TimeOfCreation** in descending order but **RequestActivity** may be null.

```
      List<DA.GeneralRequest> ongoingGeneralRequests = db.GeneralRequests
          .Where(t => t.GeneralRequestStatusID != 3 && (t.SupervisorID == currentUserId || t.CreatorID == currentUserId || t.AssignedUsers.Any(au => au.UserID == currentUserId)))
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.GeneralRequestActivities.OrderBy(ga => ga.GeneralRequestActivityDate).Last().GeneralRequestActivityDate) //gives exeption
          .ThenBy(a => a.Deadline).ToList();
```

Comment: No, the **x.GeneralRequestActivities** can be empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with LINQ-To-SQL but doesn't work `MAX` in this case?

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.GeneralRequestActivities
                         .Max(ga => ga.GeneralRequestActivityDate))
.ThenBy(a => a.Deadline)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, for some reason I though Max will also give exception. Don't know why it doesn't but First() or Last() does?

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic: Yes, `First` and `Last` are throwing exceptions if the sequence is empty. Therefore you have to use `FirstOrDefault` or `LastOrDefault`. However, i don't if if they work in Linq-To-Sql. `Max` is the better choice anyway.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` and `LastOrDefault` were also giving exceptions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first cache the ordering value, and then order by the date if it is not null, else by some default date you want:

```
List<DA.GeneralRequest> ongoingGeneralRequests = db.GeneralRequests
      .Where(t => t.GeneralRequestStatusID != 3 && (t.SupervisorID == currentUserId || t.CreatorID == currentUserId || t.AssignedUsers.Any(au => au.UserID == currentUserId)))
      .Select(x => new {
                    Value = x, 
                    OrderByValue = x.GeneralRequestActivities
                             .OrderBy(ga => ga.GeneralRequestActivityDate)
                             .LastOrDefault()) // cache value
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderByValue != null ? 
                                  OrderByValue.GeneralRequestActivityDate 
                                : some default value)
      .ThenBy(a => a.Value.Deadline)
      .Select(a => a.Value)
      .ToList();
```

Note that you can't use [`Last()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb358775.aspx) extension method on empty IEnumerable. This is why you get the exception:

> InvalidOperationException : The source sequence is empty.

In this line:

```
x.GeneralRequestActivities.OrderBy(ga => ga.GeneralRequestActivityDate).Last()
```

`x.GeneralRequestActivities` is empty, so calling `Last()` on it result on the exception.

Instead, use the [`LastOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb301849.aspx) extension method, which return `null` if the IEnumerable is empty.

> Return Value Type: TSource default (TSource) if the source sequence is
>   empty; otherwise, the last element in the IEnumerable.